# How to start animation with offset of value of last previous animation state passed time

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d, game-development

I Am creating top-down 2D game, at the moment I did stuck on animations. My character has an animation of *reloading a gun* and *running*, I created an 3rd animation of "*reloading while running*" as I couldnt blend them both well. Its kind of hard in my Top-down perspective, because if character move it uses same body parts as in reloading animation. My idea was just to have transitions set up in a configuration which would let me achive this effect. At the moment if my character is in *running* state and player start *reloading a gun* it goes to *"reload-while-running"* state, same with *reloading* (player start running while reloading a gun, it goes to reload-while-running state).

My question is, can I start *reload-while-running* state with offset of time that has passed in previous state? For example: character starts reloading, in half of reloading time(lets say 2 seconds), he starts moving so there should be transition from "reloading" to "reload-while-running" state. I want to start new state with 2 seconds offset.

I tried to achieve this through code in script by setting current state transition offset with amount of time of current state normalized Time, but this seems to not working.

```
AnimatorClipInfo animatorStateInfo;
AnimatorStateMachine stateMachine;
ChildAnimatorStateMachine[] childAnimatorStateMachines;
AnimatorState reload;

//AWAKE METHOD
animatorController = animator.runtimeAnimatorController as AnimatorController;
stateMachine = animatorController.layers[0].stateMachine;
childAnimatorStateMachines = stateMachine.stateMachines;

//UPDATE
animatorStateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

        foreach (ChildAnimatorState childAnimatorState in stateMachine.states)
        {
            if (childAnimatorState.state.name.Equals("SpaceCommando-Reload"))
            {
                reload = childAnimatorState.state;
                reloadingTransitions = reload.transitions;
                reloadingTransitions[0].offset = animatorStateInfo.normalizedTime;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered blend trees? Here my answer about them on the gamedev section: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142206/how-to-avoid-spaghetti-in-the-animator/142208#142208

Comment: I did, after your comment i tried it again and this was so obvious and easy, I was trying to solve this wrong way  :) Thank you :)